# Adding items from a text file to an array

Tags: c#, arrays

In my C# program, I'm trying to read in data from a text file to an array. I've looked at many answers on here and can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Whenever I run it, I get an exception that says that I got an unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException', but I don't understand why the index would be out of range.

Here's what I have:

```
string[] namesArray = new string[] { };

using (var sr = new StreamReader(mydocpath + @"\nameIDLines.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 1; i < numLines; i++)
    {
        nameIDLine = sr.ReadLine();
        nameIDLine = nameIDLine.Split(new string[] { "ID" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
        namesArray[i] = nameIDLine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
string[] namesArray = new string[] { };
```

You're initializing an array with length 0. Therefore, when you do `namesArray[i]`, it will always be out of range regardless of `i`.

Since you know the number of lines, and therefore the number of items, you can initialize the array with that number:

```
string[] namesArray = new string[numLines];
```

Comment: oh, okay. I was almost positive that by doing that, I was just declaring an empty array, thanks!

Comment: @asdf An empty array is an array with length 0. Your misunderstanding I think is the idea that you can insert into that array by accessing an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Trioj That is incorrect. An empty array can have a length. Think of an array as a shelf of boxes. Having an empty array with a length is like having a shelf of empty boxes. Having an array with length zero is like having no boxes at all. OP here though they were declaring an empty array of (presumably) dynamic length, whereas in reality they were declaring a zero-length array.

Comment: @stybl Ah, problem is my brain was holding different definition of "empty."

Comment: @stybl Thanks for clearing that up. I still don't understand why anyone believes there would be a dynamic length here.

Answer (score 1):

As @stybl pointed out, the problem is that you are initializing a zero-length array to store your lines... and that will always lead to an "index out of range" exception. On the top of that, I wonder how you are managing to get a consistent `numLines` value while using a `StreamReader` to parse the file... this is very risky since you must be sure that the file always contains enough lines.

I suggest you to use the following approach instead:

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(mydocpath + @"\nameIDLines.txt");
```

If you want to take a specific number of lines from the file, you can proceed as follows:

```
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(mydocpath + @"\nameIDLines.txt").Take(numLines).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is good if the priority is "using an array," but it could be easily considered bad practice if you're reading an arbitrarily large file.  Thus, I'm wary of generically recommending this approach.  Absent a comprehensive overview of file handling approaches, I'd rather the unwitting coder see an index out of range exception for having an incorrect "numLines" value than for them to hang their application for 10 minutes until it runs itself out of memory.

Comment: Or prefer [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), which avoids reading the whole file into memory at once.